# ssh connect to a machine under public IP

Tags: ssh

I tried to reach my machine through public ip

```
$ ssh me@23.100.101.9
me@23.100.101.9: Permission denied (publickey).
```

the authorized_keys

gaowei@alpha:~:

```
me@host:~/.ssh:
$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHA1MjEAAAAIbmlzdHA1MjEAAACFBAHuttEBp2wI31Ip4R9dLImfw+B1IiRApWM7RSb2ko2Z51O5kXEvLMhlr3pwszZ9yUZkfv3yqHpweqNjDbKUyDMmxABcbfBVz+JfTS+o3Dta6qenAIykepiuZu3LHZUpjx/A7HVkVnI9wnc2GN6iWkZYQvJa6sMC9dxE5rjFFu5K7E9ztw== me@host.local
```

Why it not working?

The updated authorized keys

Connet to local from it's public ip address.

```
$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBj3chjFnpxtHfeSUJVFv6fIN4CPZmIlBzuhMOOJNpovQqBc5JAhrz9uRiQIMHPD2vW+QJYiK08+6pCHthQSFrSLokLXTJfqEvb+frNEc6HvPPglGY3//97lbxR+CQYTjB/XgvnrP8sWKRt4VLfCwtCE6TqdVMx1y9SUmf7FghbHWhUioezdJaFJmfR+WVtELrUSwsc5eXcF+RS74eXEys2/v7LJF2JNYZxu0+Et7EwgxliA/5bOo6jTKBSZttBZPlsn2N7/GXnDilfAy06Iuc8MzMFCrAajQx8Nd4DG5Y33YyNVfU7eat9btUqNhpKGC+b5FGY4mkIPA2tammnjkx
ssh-rsa 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****@live.com
ssh-rsa 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 ****@gmail.com
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBj3chjFnpxtHfeSUJVFv6fIN4CPZmIlBzuhMOOJNpovQqBc5JAhrz9uRiQIMHPD2vW+QJYiK08+6pCHthQSFrSLokLXTJfqEvb+frNEc6HvPPglGY3//97lbxR+CQYTjB/XgvnrP8sWKRt4VLfCwtCE6TqdVMx1y9SUmf7FghbHWhUioezdJaFJmfR+WVtELrUSwsc5eXcF+RS74eXEys2/v7LJF2JNYZxu0+Et7EwgxliA/5bOo6jTKBSZttBZPlsn2N7/GXnDilfAy06Iuc8MzMFCrAajQx8Nd4DG5Y33YyNVfU7eat9btUqNhpKGC+b5FGY4mkIPA2tammnjkx
```

Comment: The public key should be copied to the remote `authorized_keys`, surely?

Comment: Sure, I am testing from the local machine to ssh connect to itself by public IP. copied the id_rsa.pub  to authrized_keys. @steeldriver

Comment: It looks to me like you have mixed up the host key and the user (public/private) key pair - see for example [What is the difference between authorized_keys and known_hosts file for SSH?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-known-hosts-file-for-ssh)

Comment: thank you I read the article and copied all the pubs to authoirzed keys. @steeldriver